# Change remote repository credentials (authentication) on Intellij IDEA 14

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I recently changed my Bitbucket password for security reasons. However, IntelliJ didn't update my repository to the new credentials, so it stops me from pulling/pushing anything to my repository. I am not using any plugins for this, just the integrated VCS operations inside the IDE.

Every time I pull/push, this pops out:

> fatal: Authentication failed for     'https://momothereal:xxxxxxxxxxxx@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git/

Where **xxxxxxxxxxxx** is my old password. I think changing this remote address with the correct password would fix it, though I cannot find where to do so.

Comment: all see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543035/change-git-login-username-in-intellij-idea-rubymine-etc

Comment: To solve "Auth fail" error see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984900/746347

Answer (score 239, accepted):

The easiest of all the above ways is to:

1. Go to Settings>>Appearance & Behavior>>System Settings>>Passwords
2. Change the setting to not store passwords at all
3. Invalidate and restart IntelliJ
4. Go to Settings>>Version Control>>Git>>SSH executable: **Build-in**
5. Do a fetch/pull operation
6. Enter the password when prompted
7. Again go to Settings>>Appearance & Behavior>>System Settings>>Passwords
8. This time select store passwords on disk(protected with master password)

Voila!

Note that this will not work if your password is in your URL itself. If that is the case then you need to follow the steps given by @moleksyuk [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33216283/896663)

You also choose to use the credentials helper option in IntelliJ to achieve similar functionality as suggested by Ramesh [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59565351/896663)

Comment: The menu has since been changed to Settings>>Appearance & Behavior>>Passwords.

Comment: Studio 3.1.4 Even with the option always OFF (don't store). It's still storing. So each time you miss the password you have to restart the Studio as it's consistently using that first password.

Comment: A year later: For Windows 10 and multiple IDEA 2017+ builds, this doesn't work because the credentials are stored by Windows, not the KeePass file.  See @Dush's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908824/1296767) for the fix.

Comment: I have started using the SSH way, so dont have to deal with this... :)

Comment: This solution did not work for me and may be out-of-date.  The solution by Ramesh below worked for me.  By deselecting "Use credential helper" I was able to performed a git operation like fetch where I was presented with a dialog to change my password.

Comment: Nothing works for me untill I changed the password from Windows credential manager

Answer (score 179):

After trying several answers, I was finally able to solve this issue (on window 10),

```
>git fetch
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab.abc.net/V4/VH.git/'
```

By updating the password stored in Git Credential Manger for Windows(GCM),

```
Control Panel->User Accounts -> Windows Credentials
```

Comment: Thanks! This finally worked for me. Why can't Intellij just prompt for the password on failure, like Eclipse does...

Comment: This solved my problem immediately. In my case it was under "Manage Windows Credentials" (Windows 10, Control Panel->User Accounts -> "Manage Windows Credentials") and then I changed the passwords for entries beginning with "git:". I even didn't have to restart anything.

Comment: "Windows Credentials" is called "Anmeldeinformationsverwaltung" in German Windows.

Answer (score 40):

There is an option to clear passwords

[image: There is an option to clear passwords]

Comment: In the latest version of intellij we have an option set master password

Comment: this worked for me, IJ on windows and recently my domain password has changed and I tried to execute a git command from the IJ terminal and got the 'fatal: Authentication failed for ...' error. After clearing the passwords this way from IJ settings, IJ prompted me for a fresh password.

Answer (score 35):

Doing the following steps helped in my case:

1) open Settings
2) go to Git and Uncheck "Use credential helper" checkbox
3) Do git pull
4) Enter password in the pop up dialog

Git operations will now work fine in IntelliJ[image]!

Comment: haha Checking this Use credential helper, solved the problem of Goland hanging at `go list` and all other go cmds. :) So try it but beware!

Comment: This solution worked in those cases also where you add access token instead of ID and Pasword. Tested on 2021 versions of Intellij Idea and RubyMine.

Answer (score 15):

**Linux users** (tested on **ubuntu** 14.04)

by default (on linux and mac) pycharm uses the OS's password manager. 
To access the passwords on ubuntu open the program "Passwords and Keys".

[image: icon for password manager]

Once open filter on "idea" and edit the relevant passwords.

[image: pict of password editor dialog box]

No need to restart pycharm for me.
Using pycharm 17.2

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me on Intellij 12:

Open settings -> passwords, select "Do not remember passwords" and apply/ok.

Do your VCS fetch/update/push/whatever and it should ask you for a password.

Check remember password and OK, it should do the VCS thing correctly.

Go back to settings -> passwords and switch it back to "Remember on disk", then apply/ok.

Comment: Doesn't help. The setting is to Not remember passwords.

Comment: @halxinate Yes, the "first step" was to select the setting to Not remember passwords. If you read all 4 of the steps you'll see it gets switched back at the end. Besides this advice was for version 12, which is now 7 years out of date.

Answer (score 11):

1. Go to [project]/.git directory.
2. Open for edit 'config' file.
3. In '[remote "origin"]' section find 'url' property and replace your old password with new one.
4. Press Ctrl+T in Intellij IDEA to update project.

Comment: I am not able to see pawword in 'url' property.Any other way?

Comment: it would be great if you could enter the proper steps to replace the password in the url.

Comment: credentials url should be like `https://username:password@www.github.com/myrepo.git`

Comment: Can you please elaborate the steps. I cant see .git in my project directory.

Comment: @Yasha '.git' folder is hidden by default. Enable "Show hidded files/folder" in your viewer tool. (It also depends on OS as well).

Comment: Not password, it is your Personal Access Token that must be changed in url.
credentials url should be like `https://username:your_personal_acces_token@github.com/username/myrepo.git`

Answer (score 5):

In Intellinj IDEA 14,  we can change the Git password by the following steps:

From the menu bar :

1. Select File  ->  Settings  ->  Appearance & Behavior  ->  System Settings .
2. Choose Passwords.
3. Click the 'Master Password' under 'Disk storage protection'.
4. In the Password field, enter your `old password`. Enter your `new password` in the subsequent fields.
5. Now the master password will be changed.

Answer (score 4):

For Mac users this could also be helpful:

Credentials are stored in **Keychain Access.app**.
You can just change them there.

Comment: It is very clear approach to change the GIT password in Keychain app, without dealing with IDEA password management.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, if you've already configured Git on your terminal, there's an option in preferences to use native Git rather than the built-in (bundled) one.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change in the same screen the path to Git executable.

Comment: @André oh yes, looks like I din't mark it correctly. Since we don't want intellij to use the bundled git we'll have to tell it which one to use by specifying the path. For osx and linux it should be /usr/bin/git by default.

Answer (score 4):

Go to VCS>Git>Remotes then remove your remote url from the list and add again. Git will ask for a password after next git operation (push, pull, etc). 
NOTE: Don't forget to specify username in url or you will get auth error.

Comment: This works for me. I'm using ssh key to talk with GitLab, so no password required.

Answer (score 4):

The following approach worked for me:

Create a new personal access token in GitHub and configure the connection in IntelliJ as per link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/github.html

Then, on IntelliJ, Settings-Version Control-Git screen, unclick the "Use credential helper" option.

[image: IntelliJ Git Settings]

Then do an restart with cache invalidation (File - Invalidate Caches / Restart - Invalidate and Restart)

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 10 go to:

```
Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager
```

Under Generic Credentials find your repository URL, use Edit to change your password.

After these steps, a pull should work correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The steps resolved issue for me in Windows

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Search for "Credentials"
3. Select Windows Credentials
4. Select github credentials from the list
5. Select edit and update your password then restart Intellij

Answer (score 1):

For MACOS users

if you see credentials failed but you are sure that is is working previously then:

probably you made a software update to the system. System uses git bundled with xcode. its better to open Xcode and click install extra components on startup of xcode. it will say installing components. when you accept the license agreement if will start working again.

in short:

open Xcode, install additional components. accept user licence agreement.

on Xcode updates this step should be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your password from settings screen (Ctrl + Alt + S by default) as attached screenshot. 
After clearing, on the firts remote operation (like pull/push, etc.) it'll ask you your credentials)

**IMPORTANT:** Take a copy of the file before this operation.

[image: Settings Screen]

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have cloned a project from **GitLab** to develop it. I did couple of commits too. But suddenly I had to change the access token to download another project. After that I couldn't do anything related to git in **CLION**. So what [moleksyuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33216283/13877761)  has said is true.

> close IDE > go to your local repo > go to .git directory (show if it is hidden already) > open the config file with a editor > In there,

[remote "origin"]
url = https://{yourname:access_token}@gitlab.yourorganization.com/1stdir/2nddir/your_project.git

fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

You have to replace existing name and access token with the new ones.

looks like this(https://Janith:aBhsii6Usdjbsj@gitlab.yourorganization.com/1stdir/2nddir/your_project.git)

> save > open IDE and do the git action.

Answer (score 1):

Recently Bitbucket has stopped supporting user/pass git https integration.
So I could no longer pull/fetch.

Turns out that it wasn't necessary to change the GIT Username or "authentication scheme"(from UserCredentials to Token).

All I had to is:

- Please grab an app password (or generate on via Bitbucket Web UI), and use it to authenticate.
- Use your **Bitbucket username** as a login, and **app password** as a password.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003444939/comments/360000461679

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change my user name and password in Intellij
Did it by

> preferences -> version control -> GitHub

There you can change user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac User Please Go to As Below:

(First of all you must have installed bitbucket plugin)

Android Studio -> Preference -> Other Settings -> Bitbucket

Now change your password and click on Test for verify it. Will also able to add SSH Key for login.

Also its depend on which plugin you used. Some have direct like

Android Studio -> Preference -> Bitbucket linky

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got a CAPTCHA error. If you get that, first logout/login to Bitbucket, Github, .... on the website and enter the required captcha.

After that, try again from intellij and it should prompt for another password.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it on Windows. I have git installed separately, and Idea just picks git's options automatically (Default Idea config, as I would get from clean installer).

Open the project in the command line. Make some changes there. And commit and push files via git which is installed on my machine. During push it will open a windows asking me to enter username and password. After that, when I make a commit-push from idea, it will simply work.

Answer (score 0):

None of above worked for me. Using Android Studio 3.5 Beta 4. 
I even selected "do not save, forget passwords after restart" in file>settings>appearance & behavior>System settings>password

So What I did.

VCS>git>remotes

- remove the repo and add again.
- will ask for credentials.
- then try git fetch in terminal.
- Will prompt for password.
- Issue fixed. :D

Answer (score 0):

git credential-manager  clear
Target Url:
https://bitbucketxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, just remove the remote repository (Git -> manage remotes ...) and add it again. you will be prompted to enter username and the new password.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to change git remote username/password

- Go to Control Panel
- Search for Credential Manager
- Click on Windows Credentials
- In Generic Credential section ,there would be git url, update username and password

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove it from the git credential manager.
After executing

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

the password prompt came back @ IntelliJ 2022.2

Answer (score 0):

1. Close all instances of IntelliJ
2. Start a new session of intelliJ
3. Enter "git pull" command in intelliJ terminal and it prompts for userId/password.

Javeed.mca@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

In my case, The error disappear when i checked the 'use credential helper' option in idea git setting.

enter image description here
[image]

Answer (score -2):

IN Android Studio 2.3

1. Open Setting (CTRL+ALT+S)
2. Select Other Settings (at the end)
3. select Bitbucket

Here you can change your new Password or User