# Android Studio Bitbucket password change makes existing repos inaccessible

Tags: android, git

This seems like an issue in BitBucket plugin for Android studio, I changed my BitBucket account password from bitbucket.com and after that my existing repos cannot be synced with bitbucket.

I got following error when I try to push my changes to my repos:
Push failed
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://:@bitbucket.org/.git/'

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142361/change-remote-repository-credentials-authentication-on-intellij-idea-14

Comment: Does not work.So far only method working for me is if I completely delete the project from my hard drive and checkout from bitbucket (thus creating a new folder on hard drive) this way it asks for password again and thereon works well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and fixed it by following way!

```
1.Go to [project]/.git directory.
2.Open for edit 'config' file.
3.In '[remote "origin"]' section find 'url' property and replace your old password with new one.
```

Reload the project. Done!

Comment: I am not able to locate password inside 'url' property.. I am using Git

Comment: i am also can not see password inside 'url' property

Comment: If you do not see a password, that means you did not have one - it was not required to be in the URL. Now you can add it.

Answer (score 0):

you should to add your user and password bitbucket in your gitUrl.

https://user:password@bitbucket.org/.git
if this way not work ,
you have to go in personal setting in bitbucket and go in to App Passwords and create a password and use this :
https://user:new password@bitbucket.org/.git