# Change GIT login/username in IntelliJ IDEA, WebStorm, RubyMine etc

Tags: git, intellij-idea, webstorm, rubymine

Authentication login/username for my GIT account changed.
How do I tell this to my IntelliJ product?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're talking about how you authenticate with the remote server, not which name or email address is added to a commit?

Comment: @LasseV.KarlsenYou are correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GIT record login-name in remote repository URL. You can change that in IntelliJ product in couple of ways.

### Quick way 2021

- Double-click <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>)
- Search-everywhere opens up
- Start typing *Manage Remotes...*
- Proceed as described below in *quick way*

### Quick way

- Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to open *Enter action or option name* dialog [image: Enter action or option name dialog filtering "remotes..."]
- Type *Remotes...* to filter the list as in image
- Select *Remotes...* for Git (first selection on image) and following dialog is openede [image]
- In *Git Remotes* dialog, use pencil icon to open *Define Remote* dialog [image]
- Press *OK* to confirm
- Re-enter your *password* and optionally have IntelliJ store it.

### Point and Click way

- Select *VCS* menu
- Hover on *Git* menu item
- Select from sub-menu *Remotes...*
- Continue as described above

### Terminal way

- Open *Terminal* in your IntelliJ tool <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>
- Enter command `git ls-remotes --get-url` to see your current remotes
- Enter command with modified username `git remotes set-url https://my_new_user@my.git.server/path/to/project.git`

Comment: @SackySan could you tell, which of the three solutions in this answer worked for you. I do assume that those work similarly in all IntelliJ products, but nevertheless i update the title of question, so more webstorm users would find this QA.

Comment: the first solution worked for me. you have to provide new credential next time you try to commit

Answer (score -1):

i met this problem before, and solved it by steps:

1. open terminal
2. input git command that needs to communicate with git server, like `git pull origin <your branch>`
3. input username and password ( because the stored password by idea can't be authorized, so the server will ask you to input username and password)
4. done. (idea will update the password to the user)

Comment: Does IDEA update only password or also Username when you solve it like that?