# WebStorm is not asking for password after password change

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have a GitHub account where I am invited to a repository where I work. I am not an admin of this repository.

A year ago when the repository was created I was invited to it and simply checked it out in WebStorm and was able to push and pull changes. Today I have changed password to my GitHub account and tried to update my project in WebStorm and it failed (due to new credentials).

The problem is that now WebStorm is NOT asking me for new credentials but simply shows an error screen as follows:

[image]

On the screen it is saying that the repository is not found, but that's wrong: it exists and works fine. I tried steps from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543035/change-git-login-username-in-intellij-idea-webstorm-rubymine-etc) question but it did not help. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

BTW, in IntelliJ IDEA everything worked fine, I tried to update project, it requested me for login and password as expected, and then updated the project.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from git

open the cmd if you are in windows and run this:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
```

Then you need modify the password of your git repository

After this you can use WebStorm normally