# Fatal: unable to access the requested URL returned error 403. (AWSCode Commit)

Tags: android, aws-codecommit

First time i am attempting *AWSCode* commit and it is in emergency phase. While i m cloning repository URL with **Https** in android studio it always throw an error

```
Fatal: unable to access the requested URL returned error 403.
```

For overcome with it,

1) Installed Python, CLI, MSI Installer

2) Logged in with AWS credentials in browser and my system while cloning repository

3) Set environment variable path for Python and MSI

still i m getting the same error.

Advanced help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 means "Forbidden". You need to send correct authentication credentials.

Comment: You mean do i need to set credentials through cmd interface? I have already logged in with right credentials .

Comment: No, in Android Studio if you did the checkout with Android Studio (Your question contains little detail on what you actually did)

Comment: I have already configured git in my android studio. When i open studio and select _CheckOut from version control_ using Git and clone my repository remote URL it throw above error.

Comment: Ok, then the stored credentials seem to be wrong. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142361/change-remote-repository-credentials-authentication-on-intellij-idea-14/37959112

Comment: I am just confused. I have set credentials through cmd but not getting

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after lots of research and spent time come to know that

The credentials are wrong. I came to know that it will solve by go to

```
Control Panel - User Accounts and Family Safety - Credential Manager - Window Credential Manager
```

Edit your generic credentials for your repository which you want to clone.

You done !