# github not signing in with intellij

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am working on a hybris project using IntelliJ as editor along with GitHub version control. I have added my user login in IntelliJ via File -> Setting -> Version Control -> GitHub and also added the user in Windows -> Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials. I keep on getting pop up in IntelliJ saying Login to GitHub, I tried signing in and authorize with the token, both are a success, but no luck I keep on getting pop-ups again and again. Is there any way I can fix the issue or is there anything I am missing here? Attached are the screenshots.

NOTE:- I don't have admin rights to my system.

[image: Pop-up]

[image: Authorize]

[image: Signin Success]

[image: Intellij Version Control]

[image: Windows Credentials]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [IntelliJ documentation mentions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/github.html#register-account)

> If you do not want to specify your credentials each time you sync with a remote, or push your commits, you can configure IntelliJ IDEA to save your account information (see [Configure a password policy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html#password-policy)).

Maybe it is possible said policy is not set properly.
On Windows, check you have selected the "Use credential helper" option [as  shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64568767/6309).
Then restart with cache invalidation (File - Invalidate Caches / Restart - Invalidate and Restart)

The [OP kashyap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5759359/kashyap) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246534/github-not-signing-in-with-intellij/65247900?noredirect=1#comment115445883_65247900):

> Checkbox to use credential helper was unchecked, checked that, now and it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks, working fine now. Checkbox to use credential helper was unchecked, checked that, now and it's working fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kashyap Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Roger That @VonC

Answer (score -1):

To clean cache and try again is one choice.

Also, you could try to delete the account and input same credentials to try again.

At last but not best, uninstall IDEA and install again for testing.