# Howto login to bitbucket using credentials IntelliJ (GIT) (since 12.03.2022)

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

From today I am unable to connect to bitbucket from intellij. It worked well since years, but now there it seems to be any change and I have no clue how to solve so far.

I do a fetch on my repository from Intellij and I get the following:

[image]

I give the correct credentials, which works for the login to the bitbucket weblogin.
[image]

After I entered the correct credentials I get:

[image]

In this dialog I can't change the Username, which is not an email-adress, but my name.
-> Fetch doesn't work.

In my settings of Intellij I don't use credential helper:
[image]

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change remote repository credentials (authentication) on Intellij IDEA 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142361/change-remote-repository-credentials-authentication-on-intellij-idea-14)

Comment: You may not be able to change your username since you have username specified in your URL under Git | Manager remotes.
Also it worth checking BitBucket article on app passwords (they've deprecated regular passwords): https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-git-and-bitbucket-api-activity

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bitbucket announced this:

> Beginning March 1, 2022, Bitbucket Cloud users will no longer be able
> to use their account passwords when using Basic authentication for Git
> over HTTPS and the Bitbucket Cloud REST API.
> (https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/Announcement-Bitbucket-Cloud-account-password-usage-for-Git-over/ba-p/1948231)

So you should create an "App password"
This may help:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/

Create an "App password" like this:
[App password creation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6yWV.png)

And the password shown after creation should be entered into your login dialog.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With me it only started working after I did a `git fetch` in the command line. Then I entered my App password there. Afterwards it also worked in IntelliJ.