# Github started asking for password in terminal for every "git push" after "git push origin +HEAD"

Tags: git, github

Before anything else: I'm aware of the difference between SSH and HTTPS in this case. I usually create and manage my repos from IntelliJ or VS Code, but even when manually pushing to a remote from the terminal my credentials were **never** required, even though all my repositories use HTTPS. In fact, *yesterday* I was using a terminal window to push my commits to a given remote repository and it didn't ask me for anything. Today I needed to do a `git push origin +HEAD` to this very same repository, it asked for my username and password (PAT), and now every time I want to push anything it prompts me for the password.

I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should config cache credential for linux

> `git config --global credential.helper cache`

The previous command will  cache the credentials for some time (default 15 minutes)

If you want to store the credentials for ever

> `git config --global credential.helper store`

For more information [view this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11428767/5661396)

Comment: What really bugs me is the fact that I was able to do it seamlessly before and now that. It makes no sense. And I've never had the credential.helper set in my gitconfig. I know that because I have a backup copy of my gitconfig file and it only has some basic info.

Comment: @AlexBraga I think you have a problem in credential that it store  in Linux.
Normally password store in credential after pushing the first time and you don't need to write again.

Comment: Ok, I just found something funny. When I try to `git push` from a random terminal window or from the built in terminal on IntelliJ IDEA, it asks me for the credentials. HOWEVER, if I do it from the built in terminal on VS Code, it pushes right away without requesting anything. Is vscode passing its authorization token to the terminal or something?

Comment: You should change setting for credential in IntelliJ IDEA view this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59565351/5661396

Comment: That was a good catch, thanks! It was, indeed, a matter of configuring my credentials inside gitconfig. The fact that I was able to `git push` without needing a password before is because I didn't realize I was always doing it from the integrated terminal in vscode and, like I thought, it passes its authorization to git commands, so I wasn't connecting the dots correctly in my original post